# hostedZone ID doesn't match when using custom domain for api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm using CDK to deploy aws api gateway.

The created api gateway looks like blow, and it's mapped to hosted zone `Z1UJRXOUMOOFQ8`:

[image]

My Route 53 hosted zone is this, and it only has one hosted zone `Z07841403UX33F69270EK`:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Why are these two hosted zone ID not match? I'm expecting the API gateway hosted
   zone ID to be the same as the hosted zone ID shown in Route 53, and I
   have no idea where does API gateway hosted zone ID come from as I only have one
   hosted zone in this AWS account's Route 53.
2. The API gateway domain name shown in the first picture
   `d-mtr****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` doesn't match the
   created API gateway
   `https://mmz****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/` which is
   outputed during CDK deployment.

#### Code

Dependencies in package.json:

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2": "^1.180.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-alpha": "^2.50.0-alpha.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-integrations": "^1.180.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-integrations-alpha": "^2.50.0-alpha.0",
    "aws-cdk-lib": "^2.46.0",
    "constructs": "^10.1.156",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21"
  }
```

API Gateway Stack:

```js
import * as CDK from "aws-cdk-lib";

import * as CertificateManager from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-certificatemanager";
import * as Route53 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-route53";
import * as Route53Targets from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-route53-targets";
import * as ApiGateway from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway";

import * as ELBv2 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2";
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import { ALPHA, StageInfo } from "../config/stage-config";
import * as Cognito from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-cognito";

export class ApigatewayStack extends CDK.Stack {
  // Prefix for CDK constrcut ID
  private readonly constructIdPrefix: string;
  private readonly domainCertificate: CertificateManager.Certificate;
  private readonly businessAccountAuthorizer: ApiGateway.CfnAuthorizer;
  public readonly restApi: ApiGateway.RestApi;
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: ApigatewayStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    this.constructIdPrefix = `${props.packageName}-${props.stageInfo.stageName}`;

    const hostedZone: Route53.IHostedZone = Route53.HostedZone.fromLookup(
      this,
      `${this.constructIdPrefix}-HostedZoneLookup`,
      {
        domainName: props.stageInfo.domainName,
      }
    );

    this.domainCertificate = new CertificateManager.Certificate(
      this,
      `${this.constructIdPrefix}-restApiCertificate`,
      {
        certificateName: "certificateForRestApi",
        domainName: props.stageInfo.domainName,
        validation: CertificateManager.CertificateValidation.fromDns(hostedZone),
      }
    );

    this.restApi = new ApiGateway.RestApi(
      this,
      `${this.constructIdPrefix}-restApi`,
      {
        restApiName: "restApi",
        description: "The centralized API for example.com",
        domainName: {
          domainName: props.stageInfo.domainName,
          certificate: this.domainCertificate,
          //mappingKey: props.pipelineStageInfo.stageName
        },

        defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
          allowOrigins: ApiGateway.Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
          allowMethods: ApiGateway.Cors.ALL_METHODS
        },
      }
    );

    new Route53.ARecord(this, "AliasRecordForRestApi", {
      recordName: "AliasRecordForRestApi",
      deleteExisting: true, // delete existing one instead of doing it manually later
      zone: hostedZone,
      target: Route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(
        new Route53Targets.ApiGateway(this.restApi)
      ),
      // or - route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new alias.ApiGatewayDomain(domainName)),
    });

   // Irrelevant code is hiden
}
```

#### Update

I made a stupid mistake, the record name above should be the domain name. I thought it was just a name for the Route53 record, as sometimes you can give a name to an AWS resource just to distinguish it from others.

Changing it to domain name then the whole thing works.

Now the only thing I still don't know is why the hosted zone id in the first screenshot can not be found in my Route 53.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the hosted zone that the `d-mtr****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` is located in.

You would use that to make an [ALIAS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-alias.html) record in route 53, which takes a hostname and a target zone, and this will save 1 DNS lookup compared to a CNAME

If your domain is example.com, you'd add a record `myapihostname.example.com ALIAS d-mtr****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` and refer to the zone that you're targeting.

Comment: There is also `https://mmz****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. And the CDK deployment output shows `https://mmz****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` not `d-mtr****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. I also tried `https://mmz****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` in my browser, which works, but not `d-mtr****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. That makes me feel that `mmz****` is the correct api gateway endpoint. But don't know why in my first screenshot it is bind to `d-mtr****`